# C Function pointers with parameter at declaration/ compile time

Tags: c, parameters, function-pointers

Suppose we have a list of events (int) and actions (function pointers), as in:

```
typedef struct action_type {
    int event;
    int (*func)();
} action_type;

action_type actions[] = {
    { my_event1, my_action1 },
    { my_event2, my_action2 },
    { my_event3, my_action3 },
    { my_event4, my_action1 }
}
```

and i want to add conditions to actually running the action as part of the table, for

- better readability and
- simplification of the action functions.

```
action_type actions[] = {
    { my_event1, exceeds(&temperature, 100)   , my_action1 },
    { my_event1, between(&temperature, 50, 80), my_action2 },
    ...
}
```

is there a way to get a notation like this?

Or would I need to create something like:

```
action_type actions[] = {
    { my_event1, $temperature, exceeds, 100, my_action1 },
    ...
}
```

However, this approach allows only a fixed number of parameters with a fixed type. As I am writing a library and conditions could be pretty much anything, I am looking for a way to allow different variable types and different parameter counts for the condition() function.

---

Edit: Added additional info on the conditions possibly having different numbers and types of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an X_MACRO, ie: something like this:

```
#define MY_EVENT_1 1
#define MY_EVENT_2 2
#define MY_EVENT_3 3

static int my_action1(void) { printf("Over 100!\n"); return 0; }
static int my_action2(void) { printf("Over 120!\n"); return 0; }
static int my_action3(void) { printf("Over 160!\n"); return 0; }

static int exceeds(int *val, int temp) { return *val > temp; }

typedef struct action_type {
   int event;
   int (*func)();
} action_type;

#define X_ACTIONS \
    X(MY_EVENT_1, exceeds(&temperature, 100), my_action1) \
    X(MY_EVENT_2, exceeds(&temperature, 120), my_action2) \
    X(MY_EVENT_3, exceeds(&temperature, 160), my_action3)

static action_type actions[] = {
#define X(type, cond, cb)  { type, cb },
    X_ACTIONS
#undef X
};

int main() {
    int temperature = 130;
#define X(type, cond, cb) if (cond) cb();
    X_ACTIONS
#undef X
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is actually a pretty interesting approach, didn't think of anything like this before! In this case it would create a bunch of if(cond) statements and then run go through all of them an run the specified actions.     The system i have at hand is a bit bigger (its a state machine) but I will try to figure out how this approach could work (independent of this being the final solution or not).

Comment: Yes i think it is highly dependent upon your architecture; but, if it can fit fine, i really love the neatless of X_MACROs, and their great expressiveness (ie: you can easily read your mental model from X_ACTIONS macro).

Comment: The thing is that this approach allows any number and types of parameters, as long as they match the function. That is a level of flexibility that I am not sure could be reached with another approach.

Comment: The current architecture (or rather: architectural idea) is: state/event/condition/action pairs. Sort the table by `state` (subsort by `event`) to be able to do a lookup to the first element matching a given `state`/`event pair`, then run through all the entries with the same state/event combination, check their `condition` and run `action`.

Comment: You can even have different event source types allotgether and match them with eg:
`void check_temp_events() {`  
`#define X(type, cond, cb) if (type <= TEMP_EVT && cond) cb();`  
`X_ACTIONS`  
`#undef X`

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it is a very nice solution to what i asked for and might be the right solution for someone who is looking for something similar. I like the readability of the conditions. However, in my scenario, there could be tens or hundreds of combinations, resulting in a very big amount of `if` statements, what collides with my performance goals (I want the performance to be as close to a lookup table as possible). So in my case, i will pass a system `context` variable to each callback function, that has a pointer to user data. It will not be as readable unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
#define __NO__FUNC  NULL
typedef unsigned char (*func)(void);
typedef unsigned char (*con)(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2, unsigned char param3);

typedef struct {
  int event                      
  func   custom_func;
  con    condition;                             
} action_type;
```

then use like this

```
action_type action[] = {
   { 1,SomeFunc, SomeCondition  },
   { 2,__NO__FUNC,__NO__FUNC   },
};
```

Where some func must retun unsigned char and have input type void such as

```
unsigned char SomeFunc(void)
{
  // some logic
  return 1;
}

 unsigned char SomeCondition(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2, unsigned char param3)
 {
   // logic
   return 1;
 }
```

and use it like this

```
 if (action[0].condition(1,2,3)){
    action[0].custom_func();
 }
```

you can also check if a function is set with the following example:

```
 if (action[0].condition(1,2,3)){
    if(action[0].custom_func)
      action[0].custom_func();
 }
```

Example usage all together

```
  unsigned char SomeFunc(void)
  {
      // some logic
      return 1;
  }

 unsigned char SomeCondition(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2, unsigned char param3)
 {
   // logic
   return 1;
 }


#define __NO__FUNC  NULL
typedef unsigned char (*func)(void);
typedef unsigned char (*con)(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2, unsigned char param3);

typedef struct {
  int event                      
  func   custom_func;
  con    condition;                             
} action_type;

action_type action[] = {
   { 1,SomeFunc, SomeCondition  },
   { 2,__NO__FUNC,__NO__FUNC   },
};



void main(void)
{
  unsigned char temperature = 0;
  unsigned char val = 30;
  unsigned char another_val = 50;

  if (action[0].condition(temperature ,val,another_val )){
    action[0].custom_func();
  }

}
```

UPDATE : I have added a second function parameter, called condition which can be used to check a output before executing custom_func()

UPDATE 2 : Added the condition function to accept variables as input

UPDATE 3 : I have added a example code of how to use it, however i like to point out that in your question you cannot have a variable number of arguments inside the declaration of those functions. The C syntax does not allow that.

An element is created inside the struct of type " typedef unsigned char (*con)(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2, unsigned char param3);
 "

Meaning that those element accepts a function that returns unsigned char and has a input of (unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2, unsigned char param3);

You cannot add functions that have different return type or different parameters.

Hope it helps!
Best regards

Comment: While i like everything you wrote, I think one part is missing. What you described is pretty mich what i do now. But on top of that i want to add a condition that will be evaluated before (not) executing custom_func(). So something like: if (action[0].condition()) { action[0].custom_func() }.

Comment: Hello, i have edited my answer adding a condition before executing custom_func(). Hope it helps ! Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the update, appreciate! now you are pretty much where I am right now. Now imagine i want to add parameters to condition() that the user of the library I am writing will set. so it could be `{1, somefunc, exceeds(&temp, 100)}` or it could be `{2, somefunc, between(&temp, 100,120)}`. I have edited my question to clarify :)

Comment: I have added a way to the condition function to have parameters, however in the array function they are just declared, their usage with the values is in the if statement

Comment: Thanks for the repeated update! However, this does not actually address the problem, as the `con()` function will now always be `con(uchar, uchar, uchar)`. Plus, the actual values are put in the if-statement itself. The if-statement is part of the library I am writing. The conditions, however, are set by the user of said library. So I have no knowledge of the types or the number of parameters.

Comment: Hello, i have updated my answer with an example code and more detailed explanain, in short the seconds functions ( in your case exceeds and between ) accept the same number and types of parameters and should return the same result type. In our example unsigned char. Also input parameters cannot be added in the declaration as in your example because the C syntax does not allow it. Hope it helps! Best regards.

Comment: Yes you are right, C doesnt allow this syntax. But if i have a fixed number of parameters, i can do `action_type actions[] = { {event, condition, param1, param2, param3, action} }`. But then, after how many params do I stop? And what is their type?  I think i will go with just one void* param and pass the systems context variable (that has a user data pointer) to each functio, so the users will have to manage the actual data themselves.

Comment: You can declare their type and parameters in the typedef, for example " typedef unsigned char (*func)(void); "returns unsigned char and it is of type void, if you want a function that returns void and has a pointer param simply use " typedef  (*func)(char * pnt); " Best regards!

Comment: Even though this answer hasn't helped me in this specific case (as you are basically describing the way im doing things already), it is still a good answer for people who are new to using function pointers and could be valuable in future, so thanks a lot for updating your answer so many times!